# Domino outbound as client

Tags: client, lotus-domino, sha2

Having some trouble with Domino server as client to a Web Service
Hope someone can answer a pretty easy question, but the easy question dont have a answer some I can find.

There is lots of Root Certificates in NAB 
and there is also some common Root Certificates in every *.kyr file you create in certsrv.nsf for your seerver certificates.

I get an error from SSL_DEBUG that says
[108C:005C-0D8C] 2015-12-15 19:07:19,34 SSLCheckCertChain> Invalid certificate chain received
[108C:005C-0D8C] Cert Chain Evaluation Status: err: 3659, Cannot establish trust in a certificate or CRL.

It is pretty obvious what is the problem, I need to include a missing Certificate.
But I like to know if Domino is using the *.kyr file or if it is using the Certificates in the NAB when establishing the connection to the remote server.

Anyone know how Domino acts here ?

/Stefan

Answer (score 2):

You have to find out the TLS certificate chain and add all public TLS certificates as trusted internet certificates to you domino directory.

### Find out Certificate Chain

1. Use on of this Tools:

   - For internal and external server [SSLyze](https://github.com/nabla-c0d3/sslyze/releases)

     `sslyze.exe <servername>:443 --certinfo=basic`

     Take a look at `Certificate Chain Received:`
   - For external server [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html)

     Go to the section "Certification Paths"
2. Download public certificates from CA-Webpage or get from your internal CA responsible person.

### Step-by-Step Domino Configuration

1. Import Certificates

   [Importing an Internet certifier into the Domino Directory](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSKTMJ_9.0.1/admin/conf_importinganinternetcertifierintothedominodirectory_t.html)
2. Cross Certificate Certificates

   Server: Choose your Admin Server or server where the Domino CA (not SSL CA) is hosted.

   Certifier: Choose your certifier ID or your Domino CA

   [Creating an Internet cross-certificate in the Domino Directory from a certifier document](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSKTMJ_9.0.1/admin/conf_creatinganinternetcrosscertificateinthedominodire_t.html)

   [image: Issue Cross Certificate]

### Java/LotusScript Side

The Java or LotusScript Consumer has to be told to accept CA security (stub.setSSLOptions(PortTypeBase.NOTES_SSL_ACCEPT_SITE_CERTS);)

Examples based on [Creating your first Web Service provider and consumer in LotusScript and Java.](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Creating_your_first_Web_Service_provider_and_consumer_in_LotusScript_and_Java.)

Java

```
HwProvider stub = new HwProviderServiceLocator().getDomino();
stub.setSSLOptions(PortTypeBase.NOTES_SSL_ACCEPT_SITE_CERTS); 
String answer = "" + stub.HELLO("world"); 
System.out.println("The answer is : " + answer);
```

LotusScript

```
Dim stub As New HwProvider()
stub.setSSLOptions(NOTES_SSL_ACCEPT_SITE_CERTS)
MessageBox stub.Hello("world")
```

### Further Information

Question ["Create cross certificate for Domino Java agent?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34167733/5330578) is similar but not a duplicate. It shows further aspects.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input, but that did not solve the problem.

I got solved trough 
- downloading KYRtool 
- install in /Domino folder 
- include the Root certificate(SHA2) from Web Service domain into existing .kyr file 
- restart http task

So conclusion is that it is the the .kyr file that is handling all stuff in outgoing connections

Comment: Strange and interesting. I have to try this.